# I can't see my script in Scripts tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

When I inspect my extension's page I can't see my script in Scripts tab in Chrome. My script it's just a  hello world and I've even created a .js file and included it with src attribute but it still doesn't show.

Comment: sometimes you just need to refresh few times

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else run in to the same problem, I "fix it" using the IP or domain name instead of localhost, the issue was caused for security policies

Answer (score 0):

check your the path of js file.maybe the chrome cannot find the file.